# Uncaught TypeError: sweetalert2__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...).fire is not a function

Tags: sweetalert2

I got the error on the CRUD operations.

I tried the sweetalert2 package to remove the user details.

Comment: Could you give more details about your code or file ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am fetching the API using Axios package. to delete the user data i used sweetalert2 package.